# Why is 'apply' necessary in this backbone todo-mvc sample application?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

In the Backbone Todo MVC [source](https://github.com/tastejs/todomvc/blob/gh-pages/architecture-examples/backbone/js/collections/todos.js), the function's native **apply** method is used to invoke the Underscore method **without**, and I don't understand why it's necessary.

```
// Filter down the list of all todo items that are finished.
completed: function() {
  return this.filter(function( todo ) {
    return todo.get('completed');
  });
},

// Filter down the list to only todo items that are still not finished.
remaining: function() {
  return this.without.apply( this, this.completed() );
},
```

The call to **without** looks out of place, compared to the other Underscore methods, such as **filter**. I double checked with the Backbone source to make sure that **without** wasn't mixed into the Collection object differently. Sure enough, it's not.

This is how the underscore methods get attached to Collection:

```
_.each(methods, function(method) {
  Collection.prototype[method] = function() {
    var args = slice.call(arguments);
    args.unshift(this.models);
    return _[method].apply(_, args);
  };
});
```

As expected - the models of the Collection is already passed as the first argument. Furthermore, since the methods are called on the Collection object, **this** will be bounded correctly.

I verified this by changing the method to the following

```
this.without(this.completed());
```

And that works fine.

What am I overlooking here?

Comment: You shouldn't need apply in this case as `this` for `.without` will refer to the same `this` context regardless

Comment: That's what I thought. It just seems unusual that this is the only method in the Collection source that uses apply.

Comment: That's not what I think - did you read my post?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you're overlooking anything. This is just an unnecessary call to `apply`. Probably the author originally wrote the following (maybe for an earlier version of backbone).

```
// Filter down the list to only todo items that are still not finished.
remaining: function() {
  return _.without.apply( this, this.completed() );
},
```

Comment: I just tested it and this works as well: `remaining: function() {return this.filter(function (todo) { return !todo.get("completed");});}` Any reason why I wouldn't want to do this instead?

Answer (score 2):

[Underscore's `without`](http://underscorejs.org/#without) takes an array as its first argument and a list of values to exclude from the array for the following arguments. In Backbone's case, the array that the undercore methods are working off of is the array of models inside of the collection (`collection.models`) and the list of values to exclude are the completed todos. So it's essentially

```
_.without.apply(collection.models, this.completed())
```

if there is no `apply` then an array is passed as the second argument to `_.without`, which would attempt to exclude an array from an array

```
_.without(collection.models, [completedTodo1, completedTodo2 /* , etc */]);
```

but with `apply`, the completed todos are passed as individual arguments ie:

```
_.without(collection.models, completedTodo1, completedTodo2 /* , etc. */)
```

Which is what you want so that it will exclude each completed todo.